# How to Create DDLs using T-SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, ddl

I should create target tables on Oracle and the source tables are on SQL Server now.
Since there are many tables in SQL Server, I want to make T-SQL code to create DDLs for each table, so I can run the script creating target tables easily.

Here are the steps to produce DDLs through the script:

1. Run T-SQL on SQL Server to create a DDL.
2. The script should create multiple DDLs based on many tables in SQL Server. The first WHILE loop handles the tables one by one.
   (Example) CREATE TABLE SRC_TABLE_NAME
3. The second WHILE loop handles multiple columns as the number of columns in one table and converts them with Oracle's Data Type in the WHILE.
4. Finally, make DDL for CREATE TABLE for each table.
   For example,

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE01_NAME(COLUMN1 DATATYPE, COLUMN2 DATATYPE, COLUMN3 DATATYPE,...,COLUMNX DATATYPE); 
CREATE TABLE TABLE02_NAME(COLUMN1 DATATYPE, COLUMN2 DATATYPE, COLUMN3 DATATYPE,...,COLUMNX DATATYPE);
```

Here is my initial logic and I am stuck on some points since the SQL Server has many tables and one table has multiple columns.
I googled about system objects of SQL Server and how to use them. I'm a real beginner for T-SQL and want to reduce my work time.

```
DECLARE @TableCnt INT   
DECLARE @ColumnCnt INT
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128)

SET @TableName = ''
SET @ColumnCnt = 0

-- Total number of tables
SET @TableCnt =  
(
    SELECT count(tab.name)
    FROM  sys.tables tab
)


WHILE (@TableCnt > 0)
BEGIN
SET @ColumnName = ''
SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT tab.name
        FROM   sys.tables tab
        --WHERE  -- (Q1) What can be a condition to select a table from objects list one by one?
    )

    -- Counts the number of columns of one table
    SET @ColumnCnt = 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(COL.name)
        FROM sys.columns COL
            INNER JOIN sys.tables TAB
            On COL.object_id = TAB.object_id
            left join sys.types as col_type
            on col.user_type_id = col_type.user_type_id
    )

            WHILE (@ColumnCnt > 0)
            BEGIN
                SELECT 
                        CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', REPLACE(UPPER(@TableName), '_',''), '(', 
                        REPLACE(UPPER(COL.name), '_',''), CASE WHEN UPPER(col_type.name) = 'MONEY' THEN '   NUMBER(19,4)'
                                                            WHEN UPPER(col_type.name) = 'REAL' THEN '   FLOAT(23)'
                                                            WHEN UPPER(col_type.name) = 'FLOAT' THEN '  FLOAT(49)'
                                                            WHEN UPPER(col_type.name) = 'NVARCHAR' THEN '   NCHAR'
                                                            ELSE '  ' + UPPER(col_type.name)
                                                            END, ');') 
                                                            AS ORA_CONVERSION
                FROM sys.columns COL
                     INNER JOIN sys.tables TAB
                     On COL.object_id = TAB.object_id
                     left join sys.types as col_type
                     on col.user_type_id = col_type.user_type_id
            END  
            --Reduce the number of columns when one column is completed 
            SET @ColumnCnt  = @ColumnCnt - 1;

        --Reduce the number of tables when one DDL is created for a table
        SET @TableCnt = @TableCnt - 1; 
END;
```

Comment: SQL Server has T-SQL, not PL/SQL.

Comment: Have you considered the "import wizard" in SSMS?  It is super-easy/no-brainer.  But just for tables and views. I don't think there are any utils which can convert MS stored procs to Oracle stored procs.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith -Thanks for letting me know it while I'm confused on the terms now.

Comment: @tgolisch, thank you so much for sharing that I can use "import wizard" in SSMS. I will find the menu in SSMS. I never know the function in the SSMS studio.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to import into Oracle object definitions exported from sql server directly. You will need to make modifications. Or you can use a tool like Inspirer Database Migration: https://www.ispirer.com/products/sql-server-to-oracle-migration

If you still want to go ahead and export table definitions, I will suggest you try powershell instead of tsql. You could use dbatools (https://dbatools.io/commands/) to export

```
Get-DbaDbTable -SqlInstance sql2016 -Database MyDatabase -SqlCredential sqladmin | Export-DbaScript -FilePath C:\temp\export.sql
```

Comment: Dharmendar Kumar 'DK', thank you so much for your suggestions for me! I'll look into them soon.